# Collapse a view on scroll up (iOS)

Tags: ios, scroll, tableview

I have a ViewController, which has a tableView, and has two views on top of the table view.  I need to collapse a view (outlined in red in the image), when the user scrolls up, and move another view (orange button), up with the table.  I'm planning on using the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method to detect the offset of the table, and handle the collapsing with that.

How do I go about implementing this?

[image]
[image]

```
//Custom delegate method, which returns offset of scrollViewDidScroll 
func didScrollScrollView(offset: CGFloat){
    print(offset)
    //I have the offset, which is -30 on load.  How do I implement collapsing of the view highlighted in red?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to access the frame of the view or better its heightConstraint.
**If you have a reference to the heightConstrain** you can do:

```
var previousOffset: CGFloat = -30
func didScrollScrollView(offset: CGFloat){
    let diff = previousOffset - offset
    previousOffset = offset

    var newHeight = heightConstraint.constant + diff

    if newHeight < 0 {
        newHeight = 0
    } else if newHeight > 60 { // or whatever
        newHeight = 60
    }
    heightConstraint.constant = newHeight
}
```

If you don't use Autolayout you need to update the frames manualy.

Also set clipsSubviews=true (clippedToBounds) in interface builder or in code

Comment: its making the header smaller but the labels inside are not shrinking

Comment: This is the answer, although there needs to be some editing in the code (you forgot an equal sign on the last line, need curly braces for if statement).  Make sure to set the view's clippedToBounds = true or do it on the storyboard.

Comment: Oh yes of course, I was typing freely without XCode, sorry for Syntax errors